# Woocommerce - How to order my account download by custom field

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I've added a custom column to my download page. As shown here.

```
// Callback For Account Downloads Last Updated
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_downloads_column_download-updated', function( $data ) {
    $current_post_id    = $data['product_id'];
    $product_changelog  = get_post_meta( $current_post_id, 'product_changelog', true );
    if ( $product_changelog )
    {
        foreach($product_changelog as $key => $value){  
        
            $timestamp = strtotime( $value['log_items']['1']['log_date'] );
            $new_date = date( 'F j, Y', $timestamp );           
        }       
        echo $timestamp;
    }
} );
```

I am able to see this column on the download page just fine. But I would love to change the order of downloads to show the last updated product first. I know I have to hook
`woocommerce_customer_get_downloadable_products` but seem the downloads array does not include the custom column data that I added.

Is there any way of achieving this?Thanks.

Comment: _"but seem the downloads array does not include the custom column data that I added"_ - what _does_ it actually contain, can you show an example of that? You'll probably have to fetch that meta data field based on the product ID.

Comment: @CBroe https://pastebin.com/0fsuQGHw This is what I get when I do a var_dump on the downloads array.

Comment: Most of the works seems to be happening here, https://wp-kama.com/plugin/woocommerce/function/wc_get_customer_available_downloads I guess you'll have to use the `woocommerce_customer_available_downloads` hook at the very end - loop over the downloads array, add your meta field to each entry, and then sort be that afterwards.